# Should the tag hover-text be number of subscribers, or the number of questions in the tag set?

Tags: discussion, tags, tooltips

The tag tooltip has plenty of neat information on the hover over, but the dominant one is how many subscribers follow that tag set. What information is the most useful to include in this tool tip for people who use it?

Answer (score 2):

The tooltip should contain the number of questions in the tag set.

That way, if a user is considering adding it to interested tags, he or she can know from a glance if the tag is meaningful or not.